# Silverlight button style

Tags: wpf, silverlight, blend

I am trying out new styles with silverlight, and I created a new button skin with blend that consists of a border and a textblock. Wondered if there is a way to change the the text of the textblock when the the button's content(text) property is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding would look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```

The problem is when I try to set the content to something other than text:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Content>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFB51111"/>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

In this case using the ContentPresenter would work better. It uses the same binding expression, but can display more than text. But all that is really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what your trying to do.  Normally, you include a TextBlock like that as a part of the button content.

Comment: Button content as in the button text.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ContentPresenter rather than a TextBlock in your Template.